# Mobile Web Application with Web Service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I want to write a mobile web applicaiton with jquery mobile and html5. Is it possible to call an asp.net web service with jquery ajax function for mobile web applcaiton.. Is there any sample for this? And asp.net web forms or asp.net mvc which one should I choose for mobile web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible to consume an ASP.NET web service.

Check the [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) mobile platform. PhoneGap is an open source framework for quickly building cross-platform mobile apps using HTML5, Javascript and CSS.

I propose to implement a JSON web service.

Sample Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://.../.../Test.asmx/WSMethod',
    data: 'parameter1=' + param1 + '&parameter2=' + param2,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {    
        // do something
    },
    error: function(err){
        // do something              
    }
});
```

The above example posts two parameters, the parameter1 and parameter2.

In case you don't want to post any parameters use: data: ''

Comment: ı am using this method on a asp.net web application.. but are you sure is this method work on mobile web application?

Comment: You will have to use a platform which allows building mobile applications with HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript. Check the PhoneGap platform. It is very easy to create a sample mobile app using http://phonegap.com/. The client (mobile app) does not know whether the server is ASP.NET, Java or whatever else. The client will perform AJAX calls and will receive data in JSON format.